# How to use index function to return the value of the last cell that isn't blank

Tags: google-sheets, max, row, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am keeping a dynamically updated Google Sheets file of team performance where certain cells are updated by a team member, and there is a dashboard at the top that pulls only the most recent numerical values inputted. I need to find a formula for the dashboard section at the top to return the value of the last cell that isn't blank in a non-sequential selection. for example, the cells would be:
B30, B43, B56, B69, B82, etc.

Is there a way to use `CHOOSE`, `INDEX`, or something similar to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is: don't use `INDEX`. for a last non-empty row use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("B"&MAX(IF(B:B<>"", ROW(B:B), ))))
```

---

```
=IF(B294<>"", B294,
 IF(B273<>"", B273,
 IF(B252<>"", B252,
 IF(B231<>"", B231,
 IF(B210<>"", B210,
 IF(B189<>"", B189, 
 IF(B168<>"", B168,
 IF(B147<>"", B147,
 IF(B126<>"", B126, 
 IF(B105<>"", B105,
 IF(B84 <>"", B84,
 IF(B63 <>"", B63, ))))))))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I have 12 cells I need to pull from, not an entire column:
B63,B84,B105,B126,B147,B168,B189,B210,B231,B252,B273,B294

Comment: Beautifully simple, works like a charm! Thank you :)